# Classe PHP para interação com BD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alguém conhece alguma classe PHP para integração com MySQL, usando a função `mysqli_*` e *prepared statements*?

Tenho aqui estes dois exemplos:

- [MysqliDb](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class)
- [MySQLi Database](https://bitbucket.org/getvivekv/php-mysqli-class/)

Comment: Tentou usar alguma abstração como [adodb](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/3135/php/abstracao-de-banco-de-dados-trabalhando-com-adodb/), ou um ORM como o [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)?

Comment: Não, não tentei.

Comment: Oque vc precisa fazer realmente?

Comment: O normal, inserir, remover, atualizar a BD MySQL através do PHP. Sem estar sempre a repetir o código, exemplo: `$mysqli->prepare($sql);`

Comment: Eu acho que você resolve isso escrevendo uma função simples, por exemplo no formato `JBMySQLi( $query, { $valor1, $valor2, etc } )`

Comment: @Bacco eu queria evitar estar sempre a repetir o código de *prepare*, *bind_param*, etc, sempre que estivesse a interagir com a BD, por isso queria uma classe bem feita que me tratasse disso tudo. Estou no meio da balança entre utilizar uma sugerida, ou fazer uma minha.

Comment: Estou criando algo do zero também, para o básico de consultas no MySQL com PHP. Se quiser dar uma olhada: https://gist.github.com/mervy/595fa971d4cff08bba673e4687ade66e
Vou melhorando aos poucos.

Answer (score 2):

## Medoo

Indico o medoo (http://medoo.in/) ele usa PDO e não mysqli, mas tem muitos recursos: joins, todas as operações básicas, WHERE, AND, e muitos outros[listado na documentação]. Além de uma excelente **segurança** e **documentação**, agiliza o desenvolvimento.

Ele também é bem prático e possui um sistema razoável de erros.

> Documentação: http://medoo.in/doc
>
> Download:     http://medoo.in/download

Mas se realmente precisa de algo avançado recomendo usar o próprio mysqli / PDO e começar a programar, frameworks agilizam e facilitam, mas as vezes são muito limitadas.

#### Nota

Eu indiquei uma classe com PDO porque PDO e mysqli possuem quase os mesmos recursos e foi a melhor que encontrei, e duvido muito que sua hospedagem não suporte PDO, se não suportar eu sugiro trocar de host.

#### Nota 2

Isso é apenas uma **SUGESTÃO**, existem diversas frameworks / classes por aí, você pode até fazer a sua, mas não leve minha opinião como a melhor ou certa (pode até ser), mas espere outras respostas antes de marcar alguma como certa, até porque a intenção do SO é ter boas respostas que possam ser vistas por outros no futuro, e a gama de respostas aqui pode um ser um tanto quanto "ampla".

Comment: O nome é bem sugestivo.

Answer (score 2):

Se procura soluções com ORM tem

[PHP Active Record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)
ou 
[Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html)

Comment: Vagner, seria possível elaborar um pouco a resposta, talvez destacando alguns detalhes, vantagens e desvantagens sobre essas indicações?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o próprio `MySQLi`

*PHP*

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "meubanco");
```

Utilização

*PHP*

```
$resultado = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela");
while($row = $resultado->fetch->array()) {
  echo $row["campo"];
}
```

Mais informações em [Manual PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Isso eu sei, é como utilizo, eu queria era uma classe com os métodos de inserção, remoção, atualização e seleção, de forma genérica com *prepared statements*.

Comment: @JorgeB. A própria classe do mysqli ja faz isso...

Comment: @OlimonF. a ideia era um classe tipo essa https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class que me facilitasse a interação com o `mysqli_`

Answer (score 0):

Se vai fazer na mão, aconselho a usar PDO, funções como mysql_connect e afins, estão em desuso. Versões mais atuais do php já disparam warning de deprecated quando elas aparecem no código.

Se quer usar alguma lib pronta, recomendo http://www.phpactiverecord.org/

Comment: Eu uso, como referido na pergunta, [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php)